# How to debug sql in visual studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a way of debugging sql in visual studio

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to debug stored procedures in visual studio running on SQL server. You can establish a connection to your SQL server through the "Servers" tab. Then simply open a stored procedure, set a breakpoint and run the stored procedure from visual studio with your parameters.

Didn't do that for a couple of time, but i am sure it works on any way from visual studio with stored procedures. Debugging a normal SQL command works in SQL server management studio, don't know if it work with visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

One must have SQL Server Data Tools installed *with* visual Studio. To check run Visual Studio Installer and see if you have the 'Data storage and processing` checked (*see [Install SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#install-ssdt-with-visual-studio-2019)*)

[image]

Then follow the instructions as provided [How to: Debug Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-debug-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver15)

---

In a variant answer for local instance of SQL Server and on machine apps/web services where one needs to see transactions going from , then one can **trace** the calls going to and from SQL Server using SQL Server Profiler.

See [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15)

or run the app (installed with a local SQL Server mind you) and start a trace session with all options checked and do an execute between app and local sql server.